# How could JavaScript catch exceptions raised by OCaml?

Tags: javascript, ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I have a OCaml projet, which is later converted to JavaScript by `js_of_ocaml`. I wrap some functions like follows:

```
Js.Unsafe.global##.parseFile := Js.wrap_callback
    (fun s -> Js.string (E.parse_file (Js.to_string s)));
```

Then, in JavaScript, I could call `parseFile("abc")`.

In the OCaml code, for example, `E.parse_file` may raise exceptions by `failwith "this is why"`. I would like to know how to catch this exception in JavaScript code, and eventually catch `this is why`?

```
try {
  parseFile("abc")
}
catch(error) {
  ???
}
```